# Why do I get segmentation fault in my code?

Tags: c

I keep getting segmentation fault, how can I fix that. I tryed more variants but I get segmentation fault everytime when I am using if statements. My code is something similar with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char *sentence[300];
    fgets(*sentence,300,stdin);
    int length=strlen(*sentence);
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(sentence[i]=="a")
            printf("qwer");
        else if(sentence[i]=="b")
            printf("asdf");
        else if(sentence[i]=="c")
            printf("zxcv");
//      ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first instance of undefined behavior in your program is `fgets(*sentence, ...`. `*sentence` is uninitialized.

Comment: What compiler?  Have you enabled all compiler warnings?

Comment: `char *sentence[300];` declares an ***array of 300 pointers to*** `char`, not an ***array of 300 characters***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you're doing wrong is this:

```
char *sentence[300];
```

It looks like you're trying to create a buffer of 300 characters, but what you're really doing is creating an array of 300 character pointers.  Change that to:

```
char sentence[300];
```

Then you want to change this:

```
fgets(*sentence,300,stdin);
```

to

```
fgets(sentence,sizeof(sentence),stdin);
```

Then you want to change

```
int length=strlen(*sentence);
```

to

```
int length=strlen(sentence);
```

You need to have a good understanding of how strings work in C.  If you haven't read a good introductory book for C, start there.  C is not something you're going to pick up by just reading random pages on the web and StackOverflow.